# rake with :environment gives lots of NewRelic errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, newrelic

I have a very simple rake task:

```
namespace :simple do

  task :check, [:batchtitle] do |t, args| 
    puts args
  end

  task :checkENV, [:batchtitle]=> :environment do |t, args| 
    puts args
  end

end
```

When I run `:check[foo]` it gives me the expected:

```
#<Rake::TaskArguments batchtitle: foo>
```

When I run :checkENV[foo], it gives me:

```
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : NEW_RELIC_ID does not have a corresponding configuration setting (id does not exist).
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Run `rake newrelic:config:docs` or visit https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration to see a list of available configuration settings.
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent version 6.8.0.360 in "production" environment.
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/app)
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Environment: production
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : No known dispatcher detected.
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Application: ignite-uat
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler not available: No DJ worker present. Skipping DJ queue sampler
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing Curb instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing notifications based Active Record instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing notification based Action View instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Installing notifications based Action Controller instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:15 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
/app/config/initializers/ruby_slides.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant RubySlides::TEMPLATE_PATH
/app/vendor/ruby_slides/lib/ruby_slides.rb:15: warning: previous definition of TEMPLATE_PATH was here
#<Rake::TaskArguments batchtitle: foo>
** [NewRelic][2020-04-23 19:26:16 +0000 run.* (12)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
```

I'm assuming that this means that NewRelic isn't set up correctly? Can anyone give me a pointer of where in this wall of text I can figure out what is wrong? Is it **JUST** the re-initialized constant in ruby_slides or is that just a warning on top of all of the other stuff? I'm not positive how to read this...

In case it matters, it only seems to do this when I'm running this on Heroku. When I run it locally, it seems to be clean.

ETA: here is my newrelic.yml: I deleted all the comments because it was huge...

```
common: &default_settings
  license_key: '<%= ENV["NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY"] %>'
  app_name: <%= ENV["NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME"] %>
  monitor_mode: true
  developer_mode: false
  log_level: info
  ssl: false
  apdex_t: 0.5
  browser_monitoring:
      auto_instrument: true
  capture_params: false
  transaction_tracer:
    enabled: true
    transaction_threshold: apdex_f
    record_sql: obfuscated
    stack_trace_threshold: 0.500
  error_collector:
    enabled: true
    capture_source: true    
    ignore_errors: ActionController::RoutingError
development:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: false
  developer_mode: true
test:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: false
production:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
staging:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
  app_name: <%= ENV["NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME"] %> (Staging)
```

ETA2:

I've renamed NEW_RELIC_ID to OLD_NEW_RELIC_ID, and the 1st 2 lines go away, which is good, but it still provides a lot of un-useful output is there a way to make NewRelic quiet? Or do I just need to turn agent startup as it suggests?

Comment: Sounds like there is a NEW_RELIC_ID  environment variable in your Heroku environment.  NewRelic looks any env that starts with NEW_RELIC and is looking for a corresponding configuration for ID.  Kill that NEW_RELIC_ID and you will be fine.  The ruby_slides issue is unrelated -- your initialization is trying to set the same constant twice -- it tells you where in the log.

Comment: I DO have a NEW_RELIC_ID variable in Heroku. Is that not necessary for running NEW_RELIC? (I didn't set this up originally)...

Comment: Tis a legacy value I believe -- can kill it.